# ¿como agregar "ON UPDATE ON DELETE" a una llave foránea en una tabla ya creada?

Tags: mysql, datatables

Espero que me puedan ayudar con este problema la verdad no se si tenga solución. Lo que quiero hacer es agregar las restricciones de "ON UPDATE" y "ON DELETE" a una llave foránea, pero el problema es que ya tengo creada la tabla con la llave foránea sin las restricciones que les mencione.

Esta es la estructura de la tabla:

```sql
empleado | CREATE TABLE `empleado` (
`id_empleado` int(11) NOT NULL,
`nombre_empleado` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
`segundo_nombre_empleado` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
`sueldo` float NOT NULL,
`fecha_nacimiento` date NOT NULL,
`hora_entrada` time NOT NULL,
`hora_salida` time NOT NULL,
`fecha_ingreso` date NOT NULL,
`CURP_empleado` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
/* ESTAS SON LAS LLAVES A LAS QUE LES QUIERO PONER 'ON UPDATE ON DELETE' */
`id_genero_empleado_1` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_codigo_postal_4` int(11) NOT NULL,
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PRIMARY KEY (`id_empleado`),
UNIQUE KEY `id_empleado` (`id_empleado`),
UNIQUE KEY `CURP_empleado` (`CURP_empleado`),
/**/
KEY `id_genero_empleado_1` (`id_genero_empleado_1`),
KEY `id_codigo_postal_4` (`id_codigo_postal_4`),
CONSTRAINT `empleado_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_genero_empleado_1`) REFERENCES `genero_empleado` (`id_genero_empleado`),
CONSTRAINT `empleado_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_codigo_postal_4`) REFERENCES `codigo_postal` (`id_codigo_postal`),
/**/
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Aun no se han ingresado datos a las tablas y tengo varias creadas de esta manera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes modificarla, lo que puedes hacer es borrar solo el constraint y volverlo a crear.

Primero borra el constraint

```
ALTER TABLE empleado DROP CONSTRAINT constraint_name;
```

Después agrega el constraint.

```
ALTER TABLE empleado 
  ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name
  FOREIGN KEY (columna_de_la_tabla_a_referenciar) 
  REFERENCES nombre_tabla_padre(columna_de_la_tabla_padre) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

Si no sabes como se llama tu constraint podrías checarlo con este comando.

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE empleado;
```